# BackgroundColor Items ComboBox WPF

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml

I am doing a WPF and have a comboBox which has a list of the avaible ports on the computer. I want to change the color of these items.

My comboBox is these:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="445,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"     Width="120" Loaded="ComboBoxLoaded" SelectionChanged="ComboBoxSelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Background="#849096" Foreground="White"/>
```

And these is the method to loaded it:

```
private void ComboBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string [] portsList = PrintPorts();

        // get the ComboBox reference
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

        // assign the ItemsSource to the List
        comboBox.ItemsSource = portsList;

        // make the first item selected
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

I was trying a lot of things but nothing works. Someone knows how to do it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change the background color of the individual items you can change the `ItemContainerStyle`, something like:

```
    <ComboBox>
        ...
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        ...
    </ComboBox>
```

This will set the background color on the `ComboBoxItem`s to `Blue`

Comment: Using this code a little border remains around each item...how can I change the code so that all the dropdown panel is blue?

Comment: I believe that is a valid new question. You should post it as a new question and add screenshots of what it looks like and the expected result. Note that different OSes have different styles so also mention the target OS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094770/how-change-the-background-color-of-the-dropdown-panel-of-combobox