# How change the background color of the dropdown panel of Combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, drop-down-menu, combobox, background

I want to change the background color of the drowpdown panel of the combobox.
I'm using WPF.
I've read this post

> [BackgroundColor Items ComboBox WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963236/backgroundcolor-items-combobox-wpf)

and I've written this code:

```
      <ComboBox
        Width="{StaticResource UnityX3}"
        styles:Typhography.TypeSize="Body1"
        Margin="12 0 0 0"
        Foreground="{StaticResource Viola1Brush}"
        DisplayMemberPath="AuthorName"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ConsoleViewModel.AnswersViewModel.SelectedAuthor}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ConsoleViewModel.AnswersViewModel.Authors}"
        Grid.Column="1">
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
          </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      </ComboBox>
```

I have obtained the result in the picture.[image]

I want that the entire panel is blue, included the little border around the single item.
How can I change my code in order to solve my problem?
Thank you

Comment: `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is a missing border color of the *container*. Set the `BorderBrush` value to the `Blue` for what is needed by the `ItemContainerStyle` to remove the `White` looking border.